# How to write a `ByteData` instance to a File in Dart?

Tags: dart

I am using Flutter to load an "asset" into a `File` so that a native application can access it.

This is how I load the asset:

```
final dbBytes = await rootBundle.load('assets/file');
```

This returns an instance of `ByteData`.

How can I write this to a `dart.io.File` instance?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

[`ByteData`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-typed_data/ByteData-class.html) is an abstraction for:

> A fixed-length, random-access sequence of bytes that also provides
>   random and unaligned access to the fixed-width integers and floating
>   point numbers represented by those bytes.

As Gunter mentioned in the comments, you can use [`File.writeAsBytes`](https://api.dartlang.org/dev/2.0.0-dev.52.0/dart-io/File/writeAsBytes.html). It does require a bit of API work to get from `ByteData` to a `List<int>`, however.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

Future<void> writeToFile(ByteData data, String path) {
  final buffer = data.buffer;
  return new File(path).writeAsBytes(
      buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes));
}
```

I've also [filed an issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17160) to make the docs on Flutter more clear for this use case.

Comment: Ah, cool. I ended up doing `destinationFile.writeAsBytes(dbBytes.buffer.asUint8List());` (in the debugger, I saw that `dbBytes` contained a `Uint8List`). I guess that's the same as you suggested, or is one more efficient than the other?

Comment: Remember that a `ByteData` might be a view on part of a buffer, so you might not want to write the entire buffer. I've updated the example to account for that.

Comment: For some reason, your `writeToFile` does not work for >665MB of data. Do you know if I have to set gradle.properties or similar ? Or do you have another suggestion on how to write large Files ?

Comment: @matanlurey What do you give as path?

Answer (score 25):

you need to have [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) package installed, then

This should work :

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

final dbBytes = await rootBundle.load('assets/file'); // <= your ByteData

//=======================
Future<File> writeToFile(ByteData data) async {
    final buffer = data.buffer;
    Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    String tempPath = tempDir.path;
    var filePath = tempPath + '/file_01.tmp'; // file_01.tmp is dump file, can be anything
    return new File(filePath).writeAsBytes(
        buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes));
}
//======================
```

to get your file :

```
var file;
try {
    file = await writeToFile(dbBytes); // <= returns File
} catch(e) {
    // catch errors here
}
```

Hope this helps,
Thank you.

Answer (score 20):

to search `flutter ByteData to List<int>` then found here, but not fully answer my question:

how to convert `ByteData` to `List<int>` ?

after self investigate, solution is:

1. use `.cast<int>()`

```
ByteData audioByteData = await rootBundle.load(audioAssetsFullPath);
Uint8List audioUint8List = audioByteData.buffer.asUint8List(audioByteData.offsetInBytes, audioByteData.lengthInBytes);
List<int> audioListInt = audioUint8List.cast<int>();
```

or 2. use `.map`

```
ByteData audioByteData = await rootBundle.load(audioAssetsFullPath);
Uint8List audioUint8List = audioByteData.buffer.asUint8List(audioByteData.offsetInBytes, audioByteData.lengthInBytes);
List<int> audioListInt = audioUint8List.map((eachUint8) => eachUint8.toInt()).toList();
```

Comment: Uint8List is a List<int>:

abstract class Uint8List implements List<int>

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate solution but how to encrypt/decrypt bytedata in flutter

Answer (score 7):

For those looking to write bytes (aka Uint8List) instead of ByteData please note that [ByteData is a wrapper for Uint8List](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/lGkdIn4Xu8s).

From /runtime/lib/typed_data.patch:

```
@patch
class ByteData implements TypedData {
  @patch
  @pragma("vm:entry-point")
  factory ByteData(int length) {
    final list = new Uint8List(length) as _TypedList;
    _rangeCheck(list.lengthInBytes, 0, length);
    return new _ByteDataView(list, 0, length);
  }

@patch
class Uint8List {
  @patch
  @pragma("vm:exact-result-type", _Uint8List)
  factory Uint8List(int length) native "TypedData_Uint8Array_new";
}
```

If you are using the latter type you can use the answer provided by Rami and modify the return as follow:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';


Future<File> writeToFile(Uint8List data) async {
    (...)
    return new File(filePath).writeAsBytes(data);
}
```