# How transform a dart's ByteData into a String?

Tags: encoding, dart, flutter, binary-data

I am reading a binary file and want to transform it into a String. How do I do it in Dart?

Answer (score 5):

Try the following

```
String getStringFromBytes(ByteData data) {
  final buffer = data.buffer;
  var list = buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
  return utf8.decode(list);
}
```

Also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50121777/7803650).