# Converting unit8list to video file with out creating it and its be on memory

Tags: flutter, dart, vscode-extensions

I have downloaded the bytes of a movie and stored them in a database.
I need a way to convert it back to a movie to give it to the video_player package to play.

How to convert it without creating a file?

I don't want my users to access the video files.

Comment: you could store it in a temporary directory, see https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files for more info

Comment: my bro while its playing my user can com and copy it from folder and I dont want it ! the movie files are important !

Comment: I don't think that your user would be able to access that folder

Comment: Untill the user is not using a rooted device you can do it without any problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there was no answer
I had found the way which is loading that bytes from db in to temp directory of mobile and then passing it to my player.
you could use this question.
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50119676/how-to-write-a-bytedata-instance-to-a-file-in-dart)